# Possibly simple Routing Error: No route matches {:action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I think something is wrong with my **create** method.

When I create a new resume from http://localhost:3000/ or http://localhost:3000/resumes/new, I get the routing error shown below.

---

```
Routing Error
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"resumes"}
```

The app goes to http://localhost:3000/resumes address instead of http://localhost:3000/resumes/1. Not sure why.

### Here is my code.

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
def create
  @resume = Resume.new(params[:resume])
  if @resume.save
    #UserMailer.created_resume_email(@user).deliver
    redirect_to :action => 'show'
    format.html { redirect_to(@resume, :notice => 'Resume was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @resume, :status => :created, :location => @resume }
  else
    @title = "Create a new resume"
    render 'new'
  end
end

def show
  @resume = Resume.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @resume }
  end
end
end
```

---

```
Leaflet::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :resumes
  match '/' => 'resumes#new'
end
```

Comment: What are the extra `format.xxx` methods doing in `create`? There's no `responds_to` or block Also not sure why all your resume code seems to be in a submission controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing something, but, I believe you need to alter your redirect_to statement.

```
redirect_to resume_url(@resume)
```

or

```
redirect_to resume_path(@resume)
```

That should redirect the user to the "show" action in your controller with the required parameter for determining which resume to get and show.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-redirect_to